# Dynamically changing text/contrast of entire web site?

Tags: html, css, font-size

This is using MVC 4 with Visual Studio 2013:

I am wondering on how I would approach changing the text of my website dynamically through the click of a button. This is also the same for contrast. I am wondering if there's any plug ins or approaches I can take to do this?

Heres an example of it being implemented correctly : http://www.bbc.co.uk/accessibility/guides/change_colours/# 
Giving different text sizes and contrasts etc. How would I approach this?
My idea was to have a button that calls the same CSS sheet with the new colour /contracts. But that would mean I would need about 4-5 CSS sheets that are exactly the same with just the text/contrast changing. Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: plugin needed for changing the text dynamically ?not clear

Comment: Put all your structural styles in one CSS file, which will always be referenced. Create "branding" CSS files with various text sizes and changes to contrast. Use a button to swap out references between the various branding CSS files.

Comment: Are you using a server side language (PHP, Python) and a database?

Comment: I put MVC 4 in the tags, guess it was removed. And yeah I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

May be Observables and data-binding is your best solution here.
Basically, you can bind your html with observables (your data model). When your data model's state changes, your UI updates automatically and vice-versa. It follows the MVVM pattern. 
One of the most popular libraries out their for MVVM is Knockout.js (Here: http://knockoutjs.com/) This will make your life much easier! It made mine. :-)

Hope this helps!